# "Hungry" is to "full" as "thirsty" is to what adjective?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, analogy

In Danish, we do have word for this ("set"), but absolutely nobody uses this...

Comment: As thirsty is to pissed.

Comment: Brits don't need a word for this, because the more beer we drink, the more beer we *can* drink! But I suppose lesser nationalities might be [slaked](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/slake)

Comment: This sounds like it was written by the authors of _1066 and All That_ as one of their test questions. A sensible answer seems unlikely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Along the lines of quench above.

**Slaked** - satisfied one's thirst.

OR, *drum-roll* — **Not Thirsty**!

Comment: Which is exactly what we use in Danish! But I have always wondered about this as you normally have very short words for these basic body "states"...

Answer (score 6):

You quench your thirst, so I would say *quenched*.

Comment: The question is asking for an equivalent of *full*. It is not the hunger that is full, it is yourself. But since it is the thirst you quench, it is the thirst that is quenched and not yourself. "I am quenched" makes no sense.

Answer (score 4):

There is also [*Satiated*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=40&safe=active&q=define+satiate&oq=define+satiate).

This applies to a thirst for knowledge as well as for drink.

Answer (score 3):

[Hydrated](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hydrated) or [Rehydrated](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/rehydrated) are used in sports science or medicine.

Answer (score 3):

full is not only used regarding to hunger but also thirst.

> **[full](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/full)** *adj.*  - filled to satisfaction with food or drink; "a full stomach"

Answer (score 2):

Thirsty is equal to sated. Slaked works as well.

Comment: My knee-jerk was sated, too. But, the definition seemed to work equally for food.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite term to describe being liquidly satisfied is "Replenished."

Random related story: In college, we had a dog whom we would always fool around with.  One day someone came up with the idea of trickling water onto his mouth. Whenever we would do this, he would instinctively just start licking it all up...it then became a thing: "Replenish him!!"